# Using two wireless adapters windows 7 one to connect to internet other as an Ad-Hoc network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have two network card. One is built in Intel Chipset on the motherboard. The other is an ALFA AWUS036NHV. I was wondering if it is possible for me to use the Intel Chipset for normal connecting to internet and other task while at the same time using the ALFA as an Ad-Hoc intranet network for various IOT devices that I work with. I am using windows 7.

Comment: What makes you think you can't? What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Techie007 The wireless manager won't let me do that. If I try anything both network cards start in the same mode.

Comment: You should edit information like that into your question, so answers aren't wondering/repeating what you've tried already. BTW are you using Windows' inbuilt WiFi manger, or a 3rd party one (say Intel's ProSet)?